# Overriding VB.Net TrackBar control Property -- no error, but not working

Tags: vb.net

All,

If a TrackBar control on a Windows form is selected by mouse, the keyboard left/right arrow keys can be used to decrement/increment its value respectively. Unfortunately, selecting the control causes an unsightly focus box to appear around it.

I would like to override the control's ShowFocusCues() Property to hide the focus box but retain the ability to use the keyboard keys. The following code does not throw an error, but also does not return the result I wish to achieve. Please can you help?

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Dim myTrackBar As CustomTrackBar = New CustomTrackBar

        With myTrackBar
            .Top = 100
            .Left = 100
            .Width = 200
            .Minimum = 3
            .Maximum = 25
            .Value = 7
        End With

        Me.Controls.Add(myTrackBar)
    End Sub
End Class


Class CustomTrackBar : Inherits System.Windows.Forms.TrackBar
    Protected Overloads Overrides ReadOnly Property ShowFocusCues() As Boolean
        Get
            Return False
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Comment: *"does not return the result I wish to achieve"*. What result does it produce?

Comment: You can send a [`WM_UPDATEUISTATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/wm-updateuistate) message to the TrackBar, packing `UIS_SET` and `UISF_HIDEFOCUS` in WParam. LParam is set to 0. You can do that in the Form's Constructor. No need for a Custom Control (unless you already have a Custom Control, that is).

Comment: How will the user know it's focused? Would it not  be simpler to just put the trackbar inside a panel, positioned such that the area where the focus is drawn is outside the panel? https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJDuN.png - form is blue, panel is grey, trackbar is yellow

Comment: I forgot to mention that in case a User is allowed to Tab into that Control (TabStop is set to true), that function call needs to be repeated on the Enter event.

Comment: @jmcilhinney: None, as far as I can tell. The focus box continues to appear when the control is selected.

Comment: @CaiusJard: It's true that a user would no longer see the focus box, but I can accept this. A user will normally use the mouse to drag the TrackBar to the desired value (I can set the control's ToolTip to update to indicate the value as the control is being dragged); I just would like to preserve keyboard functionality if doing so is straightforward.

Comment: @Jimi: Hello again, and thank you for your comment. No, the only reason for the custom control was to try and override display of the focus box. Currently investigating how to implement your suggestion...

Comment: Declare the SendMessage function; then, if the TrackBar's `TabStop = false`, in the Form Constructor add: `SendMessage(YourTrackBar.Handle, WM_UPDATEUISTATE, ((1 << 16) Or 1), 0)`. If `TabStop = true`, call the function from the `Enter` event. You could also do something else, maybe change slightly the control's backcolor or highlight the thumb (but that's another PInvoke call). (`WM_UPDATEUISTATE = &H0128`).

Answer (score 0):

> I just would like to preserve keyboard functionality if doing so is straightforward

I don't doubt the way Jimi has suggested in the comments is more correct, but it's really straightforward to put a eg a 300x50 sized trackbar inside an eg 290x40 sized panel, positioned at -5,-5 so the focus box is visually cut off.

Note that I don't guarantee these pixel sizes are exact/correct so they should be regarded as "for illustration of the point purposes only"; I'm on a cellphone and cannot measure the image I created to demo this, but it looks like the focus rect is less than 5 pixels...

In this image the cutoff is more than 5 pixels - I deliberately positioned the trackbar so that part of the slider is cut off to demonstrate that controls inside panels, that overhang the bounds of the panel, have their visual area trimmed:

[image]

The form background is blue, the panel grey and the trackbar is yellow

- add a panel to the form
- set your trackbar background to red temporarily so you can see its bounds
- drag the trackbar into the panel then drag it again to the top left corner
- use the arrow keys eg 5 times in the up and left directions to push it
- size the panel to the bottom right of the trackbar
- hold shift and use up/left again to resize the panel down another 5 pixels in each dimension
- if you're resizing this trackbar set the anchor properties appropriately on the trackbar and panel
- revert the background

If you don't use anchor for resize/don't know how it works, it's simplest  to consider it like:

Any edge that is anchored maintains the same number of pixels between that edge and the same edge of the container it is in. Controls try not to resize if they can

This means that anchoring left and right will cause a control to stretch if the window gets wider. Anchoring right only causes the control to slide as the window gets wider